# Unable to connect Microsoft SQL Server from Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I tried to connect Microsoft SQL Server from Tableau but I got an error message.

I opened the Microsoft SQL Server app and everything works fine.

I'm not sure what is the error.

I tried googling it but I cannot find the solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to reinstall the ODBC driver.

Comment: Do you need a domain?